# Displaying a message in a dialog box using AJAX, jQuery, and CakePHP

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, cakephp, jquery

I have a form, and when users submit this form, it should pass the data along to a function using AJAX. Then, the result of that is displayed to the user in a dialog box. I'm using CakePHP (1.3) and jQuery to try and accomplish this but I feel like I'm running into the ground.

The form will eventually be used for uploading images with tags, but for now I just want to see a message pop up in the box..

The form:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  echo $this->Form->create('Image', array('type' => 'file', 'controller' => 'images', 
                           'action' =>   'upload', 'method' => 'post'));
  echo $this->Form->input('Wallpaper', array('type' => 'file'));
  echo $this->Form->input('Tags');
  echo $this->Form->end('Upload!');
?>
```

The AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ImageUploadForm").submit(function() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", url: "/images/upload/",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      async: false,
      success: function(html){
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
          $("#dialog-modal").append("<p>"+html+"</p>");
          height: 140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $(this).dialog('close');
            }
          }
        })
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

NOTE: if I put `$("#dialog-modal").dialog({ height: 140, modal: true });` OUTSIDE of the `$.ajax` but inside the `$("#ImageUploadForm").submit(function() {` and comment out the `$.ajax` stuff, I WILL see a dialog box pop up and then I have to click it for it to go away. After this, it will not forward to the location `/images/upload/`

The method that AJAX calls:

```
  public function upload()
  {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
    {   
      echo 'Hi!';
      exit();
    }   
  }
```

$this->RequestHandler->isAjax() seems to do either absolutely nothing, or it is always returning false. I have never entered an if statement with that as the condition.

Thanks for all the help, if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST", url: "/images/upload/",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  async: false,
  success: function(html){
    //First you must append to div:
$("#dialog-modal").append("<p>"+html+"</p>");
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({         
      height: 140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    }); //dialog
  }//success
});//ajax
```

Note the first sentence:

```
 $("#dialog-modal").append("<p>"+html+"</p>");
```

it can not be a propertie. You must pass an object as a parameter to dialog() function so properties or member of an object looks like:

```
 {
 height:140,
 buttons:{},
 anotherPropertie: 'value'
 }
```

If you call to dialog() function after ajax(), the dialog will be empty because will execute before success() function declared inside ajax().

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. I'm a bit new to AJAX / jQuery so I thought it might be something simple.